# Insert text via pythons .insert() method to a tkinter Text() widget that resides in another file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 files.

`app.py` is the tkinter file that has everything tk related.

`app_functions.py` is just functions.

So when I run `app.py` and when I click on a tk button the command executes a function in the `app_functions.py` file but then in that very function it needs to `.insert()` text to a tk `Text()` widget in the `app.py` file. But I am getting errors.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Phil-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Phil-\python_main\gsc script building app\app.py", line 30, in <lambda>
    button1 = Button(content_frame1, text="INIT_Function", command=lambda: app_functions.display_raw_gsc_code("INIT_FUNCTION_START", "INIT_FUNCTION_END"))
  File "c:\Users\Phil-\python_main\gsc script building app\app_functions.py", line 45, in display_raw_gsc_code
    content_frame2_text_area.insert(tk.END, line)
NameError: name 'content_frame2_text_area' is not defined
```

When I import the `app.py` file within the `app_functions.py` file and then run the `app.py` file it loads up the gui and then once I click on the button it then opens up the tk gui again so that is no good.

So in short I am able to execute a function thats in another file from a tk button as I successfully managed to import the function.
But in that function it needs to `.insert()` text to a tk widget in another file, but this is not working out for me and all examples online include having the function in the same file as the tk button & tk `Text()` widget and sure it works, but i want to keep tk stuff and functions in separate files.

##### Basic concept of what im trying to accomplish:

1. click button in app.py which executes a function called `display_raw_gsc_code` in `app_functions.py`
2. `display_raw_gsc_code` function in `app_functions.py` does its job and then inserts text to a `Text()` widget in `app.py`
3. `Text()` widget in `app.py` displays the received text.

##### BUTTON IN TK (`app.py`) FILE

```
button1 = Button(content_frame1, text="INIT_Function", command=lambda: app_functions.display_raw_gsc_code("INIT_FUNCTION_START", "INIT_FUNCTION_END"))
```

##### FUNCTION IN FUNCTIONS(app_functions.py) FILE

```
def display_raw_gsc_code(start, end):
    """ grab gsc 'example code' from raw file & display in output(frame2) area """
    f = open(join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), "raw_gsc_code.txt"), 'rt')
    with f as file:
        copy = False
        for line in file:
            if line.strip() == start:
                copy = True
                continue
            elif line.strip() == end:
                break
            elif copy:
                content_frame2_text_area.insert(tk.END, line)
    f.close()
```

##### TEXT WIDGET IN TK(app.py) FILE

```
content_frame2_text_area = Text(content_frame2, relief="ridge", bd=2) #GROOVE
content_frame2_text_area.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="ns", padx=5, pady=5)
```

Comment: You need to pass `content_frame2_text_area` as an argument of `display_raw_gsc_code()`.

Comment: that worked right away. thank you so much :)

Comment: how do i mark your answer as best answer / mark this question as solved?

Comment: You can write an answer yourself and accept it to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `content_frame2_text_area` as an argument of `display_raw_gsc_code()`